# Unable to add new field option to dobtco formbuilder plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, rivets.js

I am building a web application in which I am using this form builder plugin: https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder.

I am trying to add a new field option that will be visible in all form fields. Like this:

```
Formbuilder.options = {
            BUTTON_CLASS: 'fb-button',
            HTTP_ENDPOINT: '',
            HTTP_METHOD: 'POST',
            AUTOSAVE: false,
            CLEAR_FIELD_CONFIRM: false,
            mappings: {
                SIZE: 'field_options.size',
                UNITS: 'field_options.units',
                LABEL: 'label',
                FIELD_TYPE: 'field_type',
                REQUIRED: 'required',
                ADMIN_ONLY: 'admin_only',
                OPTIONS: 'field_options.options',
                DESCRIPTION: 'field_options.description',
                INCLUDE_OTHER: 'field_options.include_other_option',
                INCLUDE_BLANK: 'field_options.include_blank_option',
                INTEGER_ONLY: 'field_options.integer_only',
                MIN: 'field_options.min',
                MAX: 'field_options.max',
                MINLENGTH: 'field_options.minlength',
                MAXLENGTH: 'field_options.maxlength',
                LENGTH_UNITS: 'field_options.min_max_length_units',
                SAVE_X_INFO: 'save_x_info' /* <--- This is added by me */
            },
            dict: {
                ALL_CHANGES_SAVED: 'All changes saved',
                SAVE_FORM: 'Save form',
                UNSAVED_CHANGES: 'You have unsaved changes. If you leave this page, you will lose those changes!'
            }
        };
```

The HTML code for this field option is generated using this code:

```
var infoSelectorHTML = '<div id="infos" style="display:inline-block"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="edit" onclick="tagInfo(\'infos\'); return false"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Select</button>';
this["Formbuilder"]["templates"]["edit/save_x_info"] = function (obj) {
    obj || (obj = {});
    var __t, __p = '',
        __e = _.escape;
    with (obj) {
        __p += '<div class=\'fb-edit-section-header\'>Save to Infos: </div>' + infoSelectorHTML + '<input id=\'fbInfoHidden\' style=\'display: none\' type="text" data-rv-input="model.' + ((__t = (Formbuilder.options.mappings.SAVE_X_INFO)) == null ? '' : __t) +
            '" />\n\n&nbsp;&nbsp;\n';
    }
    return __p
};
```

Now, this code works as follows:

1. User clicks `Select` button. A popup is opened.
2. From that popup user selects his/her profile info.
3. The `ID` of that info is saved inside `#fbInfoHidden` textbox.
4. This `ID` is now fetched by the form builder when saving data.

Problem starts from step 3. The `ID` sent by the popup is not assigning to the textbox's value. Here is the code that I am using to assign it:

```
function updateFBInfoData(fbInfoData) {
    var fbInfoHidden = $('#fbInfoHidden');
    if (fbInfoHidden != null)
        fbInfoHidden.val(fbInfoData);
}
```

`fbInfoData` is successfully receiving `ID` from the popup. But not assigning to `fbInfoHidden` textbox. Please tell me the reason for this?

And another problem in the form builder I am facing is that before using `fbInfoHidden` as a textbox, I was using it like a hidden field. That time `ID` was successfully assigned to `fbInfoHidden` hidden field. But at that time when form is saved, it's still not getting the value for `save_x_info` in the json data. Please tell me the solution in either of these two cases.

This plugin uses [rivets.js](http://rivetsjs.com), [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org), [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) plugin and I don't know a single thing about these plugins. As I only used pure JavaScript and JQuery till now. So unable to understand much of the code. Please tell me how to configure this to add custom field options.

**UPDATE**

This is how I am initializing form builder:

```
var formDesignData = $('#formDesignData').val();
    if (formDesignData == null)
        formDesignData = '[{}]'
    fb = new Formbuilder({
        selector: '.fb-main',
        bootstrapData: JSON.parse(formDesignData)
    });

    fb.on('save', function (payload) {
        SaveFormDesign(payload);
    })
```

**UPDATE 2**

The reason why the value of `save_x_info` is not being fetched from the field is because the data added to the textbox from the popup is not fetched but the data entered manually is being fetched successfully. I don't know why it is happening. But I know that it has something to do with `rivets.js` can you please tell me how to fix it?