# on('change:') event not accepting textbox value when changed using some popup but when changed manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, rivets.js

Continuing from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685866/unable-to-add-new-field-option-to-dobtco-formbuilder-plugin).

I am using [dobcto formbuilder](https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder) plugin. This plugin uses [rivets.js](http://rivetsjs.com/) and [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/).

In my previous question I was unable to figure out what was going wrong but then after `12 hours` of research into that plugin code. I found that the problem is when the data is added to the `textbox` using some popup.

When we add manually through keyboard, the change event triggers successfully and textbox data is added to the JSON result.

I gone through rivets.js documentation and read everything about it. But this plugin uses old version of rivets.js and I don't want to update that now because project submission date is coming and I have a lot of work to do.

#### So if it can be solved in this version than it will be great. The plugin initializes rivets.js like this:

```
(function () {
    rivets.binders.input = {
        publishes: true,
        routine: rivets.binders.value.routine,
        bind: function (el) {
            return $(el).bind('input.rivets', this.publish);
        },
        unbind: function (el) {
            return $(el).unbind('input.rivets');
        }
    };

    rivets.configure({
        prefix: "rv",
        adapter: {
            subscribe: function (obj, keypath, callback) {
                callback.wrapped = function (m, v) {
                    return callback(v);
                };
                return obj.on('change:' + keypath, callback.wrapped);
            },
            unsubscribe: function (obj, keypath, callback) {
                return obj.off('change:' + keypath, callback.wrapped);
            },
            read: function (obj, keypath) {
                if (keypath === "cid") {
                    return obj.cid;
                }
                return obj.get(keypath);
            },
            publish: function (obj, keypath, value) {
                if (obj.cid) {
                    return obj.set(keypath, value);
                } else {
                    return obj[keypath] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    });

}).call(this);
```

Even after reading rivets documentation I am unable to understand this code. So please tell me how to change this initialization process so that it accepts the textbox text that is added by the popup?

Answer (score 0):

I humbly admit that I cannot follow the above logic.  However, I have found that binding `propertychange` or `input` to an event yield better results than `change`.

```
(function () {
    rivets.binders.input = {
        publishes: true,
        routine: rivets.binders.value.routine,
        bind: function (el) {
            return $(el).bind('input.rivets', this.publish);
        },
        unbind: function (el) {
            return $(el).unbind('input.rivets');
        }
    };

    rivets.configure({
        prefix: "rv",
        adapter: {
            subscribe: function (obj, keypath, callback) {
                callback.wrapped = function (m, v) {
                    return callback(v);
                };
                return obj.on('change:' + keypath, callback.wrapped);
            },
        this.on('propertychange input', function (changeSwap) { unsubscribe: function(obj, keypath, callback) { return obj.off('change:' + keypath, callback.wrapped); }, });,
            read: function (obj, keypath) {
                if (keypath === "cid") {
                    return obj.cid;
                }
                return obj.get(keypath);
            },
            publish: function (obj, keypath, value) {
                if (obj.cid) {
                    return obj.set(keypath, value);
                } else {
                    return obj[keypath] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: The problem is that the plugin highly depends on this code. Check out here: https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder/blob/gh-pages/dist/formbuilder.js.

Comment: Since it only occurs in 4 places (using search), would it be possible to wrap those 4 lines in a more user friendly trigger event?

For example, take the following line

`return obj.off('change:' + keypath, callback.wrapped);`

....To something like this.....

`this.on('propertychange input', function (changeSwap) {
      unsubscribe: function(obj, keypath, callback) {
        return obj.off('change:' + keypath, callback.wrapped);
      },
});`


The goal, I gander, would be to add additional functionality without affecting any of the built in working code.
@AishwaryaShiva

Comment: Where should I add this code? Can you please edit my code and tell me?

Comment: Answer updated for the gist.  The line I changed is the `unsubscribe:` If it does not work, there, you may have to leave it as is, and invoke the ENTIRE function in another variable altogether (if that is possible).

Comment: Don't you think that this will cause syntax error as it is added between option definition?

Comment: Perhaps, which is why I recommended the fall back of wrapping the entire function into the bound event.